# Python - How to get entry widget to add instead of concatenate?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to get two separate entry widgets to add whatever is in them, but problem right now is it is concatenating the numbers in the entry widget.

```
from tkinter import *

master = Tk()

class MainWindow:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.geometry("640x480")


def Calculate():
    entry1 = firstEntry.get()
    entry2 = secondEntry.get()
    result = entry1 + entry2
    print(result)


firstLabel = Label(text="First Value")
firstLabel.grid(row=1, column=1)

firstEntry = Entry(master)
firstEntry.grid(row=1, column=2)

addLabel = Label(text="+")
addLabel.grid(row=1, column=3)

secondEntry = Entry(master)
secondEntry.grid(row=1, column=4)

secondLabel = Label(text="Second Value")
secondLabel.grid(row=1, column=5)

equalsButton = Button(text="=", width=10, command=Calculate)
equalsButton.grid(row=2, column=3)

master.mainloop()
```

Comment: have you considered simply changing the values to integers before doing the calculation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `+` operator, in Python, has a meaning with both strings and numbers (among other).
For numbers, it represents the natural (in the sense of "common") addition:

```
>>> 1 + 1
2
```

On the other hand, for strings, it represents the concatenation:

```
>>> "Hello" + ", world!"
'Hello, world!"
```

The `get` method of `tkinter.Entry` instances returns a string object, ie an instance of `str`.
As a consequence, `entry1 = firstEntry.get()` and `entry2 = secondEntry.get()` both give you a string, whether or not the input contains digits.
Then, `entry1 + entry2` results in a string, that is the concatenation of `entry1` and `entry2`.

Therefore, you need to convert beforehand the content of your entries into either integers or floating-point numbers, the latter being more general.
Your `Calculate` function could become:

```
def Calculate():
    entry1 = float(firstEntry.get())
    entry2 = float(secondEntry.get())
    result = entry1 + entry2
    print(result)
```

Be careful however, that the `float` function will raise a `ValueError` if the conversion could not be performed.
The following would be more prudent:

```
def Calculate():
    try:
        entry1 = firstEntry.get()
        entry2 = secondEntry.get()
        result = entry1 + entry2
        print(result)
    except ValueError:
        print("Please type in valid numbers")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from tkinter import *

master = Tk()

class MainWindow:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.geometry("640x480")


def Calculate():
    entry1 = firstEntry.get()
    entry2 = secondEntry.get()
    result = int(entry1) + int(entry2)
    print(result)


firstLabel = Label(text="First Value")
firstLabel.grid(row=1, column=1)

firstEntry = Entry(master)
firstEntry.grid(row=1, column=2)

addLabel = Label(text="+")
addLabel.grid(row=1, column=3)

secondEntry = Entry(master)
secondEntry.grid(row=1, column=4)

secondLabel = Label(text="Second Value")
secondLabel.grid(row=1, column=5)

equalsButton = Button(text="=", width=10, command=Calculate)
equalsButton.grid(row=2, column=3)

master.mainloop()
```

Just typecaste the result of entry.get  by int(firstentry.get()) and int(secondentry.get()) otherwise it will lead to addition of strings that is

"4"+"5" = "45"